# horizontally centering a UL in a DIV

Tags: css, html, center

I have a `ul` inside a `div`. I want to center it. Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LyJz9/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu-top">
   <div id="menu-container">
      <div id="menu-mask">
         <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu-top {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 26px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
}

#menu-container {
    width: 840px;
    margin: auto;
}

#menu-mask {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 26px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 800px;
}

#menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 26px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li {
    padding-right: 20px;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}

#menu li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...   change your #menu to this:

```
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:25%;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    top: 0px;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The margin-left and margin-right settings will center your menu on the page.   I gave this a quick test in your JSFiddle to make sure it works.

Oh, and here's the updated JSFiddle showing the changes...
http://jsfiddle.net/LyJz9/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `text-align:center` for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try to put it in #menu and see if that does the trick? Because it looks like you use <ul  id="menu"> if not there try in menu li { } and if not there you can try in menu li a { }